# How can I set NeoVim to automatically source .vimrc?

Tags: nvim

Each time I open NeoVim, I have to type `:so .vimrc` (it is located inside of my `$HOME` folder) for it to load the file.

I've tried googling my way out of it, but I can't seem to get any results on what I want to do. The results are stuff like "auto source vimrc when saved", "reload vimrc without restart" etc. and none of these worked, either.

Is it possible to automatically source that file upon startup instead of manually typing it each time I open `nvim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NeoVim editor uses `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

See [the `vimrc-intro` section](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_05.html#vimrc-intro) in the NeoVim manual.

You could also set `VIMINIT` to the Ex command `so ~/.vimrc` to force the sourcing of the `~/.vimrc` file, as described in [the `$MYVIMRC` section](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#$MYVIMRC).

Comment: Magnificent!! Worked a charm. All i had to do was to add `source $HOME/.vimrc` and it autoloads the file now. Thanks :)